# Parent directive controller not available?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive called `<popup>` that contains a number of `<popup-link>`-directives. When a `<popup-link>` is clicked, the parent `<popup>` directive should be closed by invoking a function `close()` on its controller.

For some reason I cannot get the controller instance of `<popup>`, as it is not injected correctly to the link function of `<popup-link>`

I get the below error and the inspecting the object yields **instantiate.c** ?

> Object [object Object] has no method 'close'

What am I doing wrong?

```
directive('popup', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div id="{{ popupId }}" class="navigatorPopup" ng-transclude></div>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.close = function () {
                //close popup
            };
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            //
        }
    }
}).
directive('popupLink', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '^popup',
        template: '<h3 ng-bind="title"></h3>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            ngClick: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, popupCtrl) {
            scope.popupCtrl = popupCtrl;
            element.bind('click', 
                function () {
                    scope.popupCtrl.close();
                    scope.ngClick();
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

And the HTML

```
<popup name="menuNavigator">
   <popup-link ng-repeat="category in getCategories()" title="{{ category.Title }}" ng-click="navigateMenu($index)"></popup-link>
</popup>
```

Thanks!

Comment: For an explanation of why you need to define `close` on the controller rather than the `$scope`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child controller is requiring an instance of the parent controller.  Treat the "public" components of the parent controller as, well, public.

Change `$scope.close = function(){..}` to `this.close = function(){..}`

Also, it is not *necessary* to explicitly set `popupCtrl` to the local scope as you did in your child link function. You can access the parent function directly with:

`popupCtrl.close()`

Unless you just prefer that naming convention...

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/siaChpeMwiC8cDUTz3lj?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You're not wrapping an `scope.$apply` around methods within the click handler:

```
element.bind('click', 
    function () {
        scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.popupCtrl.close();
            scope.ngClick();
        });
    }
);
```

You need to wrap any code that happens outside of AngularJS' [$apply/$digest loop](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime) with a scope.$apply method so that Angularjs is aware that the change has happened.

Editted:

Sorry i misread question.

The reason this is happening is you're putting the function on the scope property instead of the controller:

```
controller: function ($scope) {
    $scope.close = function () {
        //close popup
    };
},
```

should be:

```
controller: function ($scope) {
    this.close = function () {
        //close popup
    };
},
```

Comment: This is true for instances such as scope variables being modified within the handler.  But in this case, if you are just calling other functions, they will fire without the $apply.